# Pipe all Postfix email for a domain to PHP script - Centos7/EC2

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, smtp, email-server

I've read a few articles, including posts on here, but there doesn't seem to be a clear concise answer.

I have CentOS7 running Postfix on an EC2 instance on AWS. I want to direct all emails for a domain (@support.mydomain.com) to a PHP script. The server hostname is not set to the domain (hostname is default ip-1-2-3-4.awsregion.internal.compute).

I have set an MX record for support.mydomain.com to point to www.mydomain.com.

From what I have read, I need a `virtual alias` to handle the domain.

I have tried:

- adding `@support.mydomain.com apache@localhost` to `/etc/postfix/virtual`
- running `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
- adding `virtual_alias_maps = :hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` and `inet_interfaces=all` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
- adding `apache: "|php -q /var/www/mydomain/my-script.php"`
- newaliases
- postfix reload
- service postfix restart

`/var/log/maillog` shows email a ```454 4.7.1 Relay access denied" error - at least this shows DNS/firewalls are OK ...

Would appreciate where to go from here or a new guide from the start.

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly, Wombles comment helped and I was very close with my initial question.

This worked for me. This is to redirect/pipe all email for one domain (not in hostname) to a php script on a CentOS server using Postfix (assuming you have deal with DNS and selinux/firewalls):

1. Virtual Alias

   Redirect the email to a local user by updating `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

   `@support.mydomain.com       apache@localhost`

   Rebuild the virtual alias db with `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`.
2. Tell Postfix To Use Our Virtual Alias db in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

   `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`
3. Virtual Domain

   Update `/etc/postfix/main.cf` with a virtual domain, so it knows to accept email for your the domain, otherwise you'll get a "454 4.7.1 Relay access denied" error:

   `virtual_alias_domains = support.mydomain.com`
4. Accept Connections

   Tell postfix to allow connections from the internet (not jsut local) by upadting `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

   `inet_interfaces=all`
5. Update Alias

   Update `/etc/aliases` to redirect email addressed to the localuser to a script:

   `#apache:root` (unconnect any existing entry for your local user)
   `apache: "|sudo /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/mydomain.com/my-script.php"`
6. Rebuild Aliases & Restart Postfix

   `sudo newaliases`
   `sudo postfix reload`
   `sudo service postfix restart`

I hope this helps others, there didn't seem to be a compiled/concise post on this.