# Ways to integrate incoming and outgoing mail webhook in Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, php, postfix

I am trying to build an application in PHP which will be able to create a Ticket whenever a new mail arrives on a specific account and whenever a reply is done for that email, the application will delete the ticket.

We are using Self-Hosted Postfix in Ubuntu environment.

Is there a way in postfix to intercept the incoming and outgoing emails of a specific account? something like a Webhook which can give access to the incoming and outgoing email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe all Postfix email for a domain to PHP script - Centos7/EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/881096/pipe-all-postfix-email-for-a-domain-to-php-script-centos7-ec2)